# How to know why a service was restarted by systemd?

Tags: systemd, logs, rsyslog, systemctl

I have a host running rsyslog which uses imuxsock to accept messages from journald. However, during boot, after rsyslog is started, it is restarted (stopped and started) again by systemd. I need to know why systemd did this.

**How can we know what caused systemd to restart a service ?** (in this case, it was soon after initial start)

I am facing an issue where for the time difference of a minute or so between journald start and rsyslog start, i only see kernel messages in rsyslog (and no user-space messages). However, after rsyslog start time, user-space messages are also seen. I guess the unexpected restart may have something to with this.

I have "`Restart=on-failure`" in the service file.

Here are the logs from my host which don't provide a clue for the cause of restart.

```
host_1:/home/admin# journalctl -u rsyslog --no-pager
-- Logs begin at Thu 2019-10-24 15:01:58 UTC, end at Thu 2019-10-24 17:20:37 UTC. --
Oct 24 15:03:25 host_1 rsyslogd[5332]: environment variable TZ is not set, auto correcting this to TZ=/etc/localtime  [v8.36.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2442 ]
Oct 24 15:03:25 host_1 rsyslogd[5332]: imuxsock: Acquired UNIX socket '/run/systemd/journal/syslog' (fd 3) from systemd.  [v8.36.0]
Oct 24 15:03:25 host_1 rsyslogd[5332]:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.36.0" x-pid="5332" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Oct 24 15:03:25 host_1 systemd[1]: Starting System Logging Service...
Oct 24 15:03:25 host_1 systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
Oct 24 15:03:26 host_1 systemd[1]: Stopping System Logging Service...
Oct 24 15:03:26 host_1 rsyslogd[5332]:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.36.0" x-pid="5332" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
Oct 24 15:03:26 host_1 systemd[1]: Stopped System Logging Service.
Oct 24 15:03:26 host_1 systemd[1]: Starting System Logging Service...
Oct 24 15:03:26 host_1 rsyslogd[6201]: environment variable TZ is not set, auto correcting this to TZ=/etc/localtime  [v8.36.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2442 ]
Oct 24 15:03:26 host_1 systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
Oct 24 15:03:26 host_1 rsyslogd[6201]: imuxsock: Acquired UNIX socket '/run/systemd/journal/syslog' (fd 3) from systemd.  [v8.36.0]
Oct 24 15:03:26 host_1 rsyslogd[6201]:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.36.0" x-pid="6201" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
```